# Filter first then select page

Tags: sql-server

How to first filter the result based on params then to apply where-between?
Some thing like

```
With Results as
(
    Select colName,Title, Row_Number(Over...) as row from a table where colName=5
)
Select * from Results 
where 
row between @first and @last
```

But it does not works. I need to move my where colName=5 from with clause to outside then I got wrong data as It first get rows between @first n @last then search for colName=5.
Also I want count of Results.

Any idea?

Comment: *I need to move my where colName=5 from with clause to outside* - Why do you think you need to do that? It shouldn't be necessary, and doing so will give you a wrong result as you have already discovered. So why do you want to do it?

Comment: Do you think it is a clever idea to call a column a numeric type colName ? And what do you mean by does not work ? Syntax errors, wrong result?

Comment: The presentation of the question isn't optimal, but I do not like downvoters leaving no comments. I voted it back to zero.

Comment: I need to return count of Results in some output param. But It looks I can use Results only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(*) OVER()` to get the count of the unfiltered results

```
WITH cte as
(
select *, 
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by name desc) AS RN, 
count(*) over() AS [Count]
from master..spt_values
)
SELECT name, number,[Count] 
FROM cte
WHERE RN BETWEEN 20 AND 24
```

Returns

```
name                                number      Count
----------------------------------- ----------- -----------
VIEW                                8278        2506
VIEW                                8278        2506
view                                2           2506
varchar                             3           2506
varbinary                           1           2506
```

This has performance implications though. You might want to just calculate the COUNT up front and cache it somewhere rather than recalculating it for every page request.

Answer (score 1):

Your ROW_NUMBER syntax is incorrect. It should be this:

```
With Results as
(
    SELECT colName, Title, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) AS RN
    FROM your_table
    WHERE colName = 5
)
SELECT * FROM Results 
WHERE rn BETWEEN @first AND @last
ORDER BY rn
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Yes thats what I was looking for, but can you please tell me how can I get the count of Results in some output param?

Comment: direct after execution of Marks query it is in @@rowcount

Comment: @bernd_k - I suspect the OP wants the count of the non paged results to know how many page links to display.

Comment: can I set @@rowcount in some output param? How?

Comment: yes, when you have an output parameter @ooutpar add a line select @outpar = @@rowcount

Answer (score 0):

I use approach very similar to Martin Smiths (currently selected answer) and at least in the tests I've made it gives better performance results.

```
; WITH cte as
(
select *, 
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by name desc) AS RN
from master..spt_values
)
SELECT name, number, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte) AS [Count]
FROM cte
WHERE RN BETWEEN 20 AND 24
```

Run this and his queries side by side and compare execution plans.